# NetCat : respond to client w/their ip?

Tags: netcat

IP address of CLIENT is in this $VAR:

```
VAR=$(nc -v -l 80 2>&1)
```

I can further refine it.

How to send this $VAR back to the client
without running another netcat command ?

With other programming languages..
IP can be obtained prior to sending a response.
and thus can be included in the response.

Not possible with netcat ?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's possible. Just set up `nc` as a co-process:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# Greets the client with their hostname.

coproc ( nc -l -v localhost 3000 2>&1 )

{
    declare "$( sed -e 's/^Connection from \([^ ]*\).*$/client="\1"/' -e 'q' )"
    printf 'Hello there, user on %s\n' "$client"
} <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

For something more advanced, like handling HTTP requests:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Handles one request, then kills nc and restarts

while true; do
    coproc ( nc -l localhost 3000 2>&1 )

    {
      get_http_request_header
      process_request
      send_http_reply
    } <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}

    kill "$COPROC_PID"
done
```

The commands `get_http_request_header`,
        `process_request`, and
        `send_http_reply` may be shell functions or separate scripts that you write.

The `get_http_request_header` routine would get its standard input from the client connected to `nc` and would parse the request, possibly storing it in a temporary file or setting some global variables or in some other way passing the needed information to `process_request`.

`process_request` may handle compiling the result in whatever way is necessary.

`send_http_reply` would print to the client by simply writing to standard output.

Another possible setup where the information on the server side is simply passed along the internal steps through pipes:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Handles one request, then kills nc and restarts

while true; do
    coproc ( nc -l localhost 3000 2>&1 )

    {
      get_http_request_header |
      process_request |
      send_http_reply
    } <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}

    kill "$COPROC_PID"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered or whereabouts in [display-welcome-message-upon-successful-netcat-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173017/display-welcome-message-upon-successful-netcat-connection)

But essentially, you'll do as follows with your listener:

```
(echo "$VAR"; cat) |nc -nvlp 4444
```

When your client connects, the listener echoes this variable onto the client's stdout.